# how to remove chars into a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, substring

I have a lot of strings, and I need to delete '0' at start of string, but what is the better way to do it, because this is an example of strings:

```
0130799.jpg //I need to get 130799
0025460.jpg //I need to get 25460
```

Now, I'm using substr function, but I think it's more efficient if I'll use Regex no ?

Comment: As to the efficiency of a regex over another method see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303355/substring-match-faster-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just type cast will do it efficiently

```
echo (int) $var;
```

Comment: Indeed, it was easy ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

If the format is the same for all strings ([numbers].jpg), you could do:

```
intval('0130799.jpg', 10);
```

[intval() in Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `substr` you have to use it in conjunction with `strpos` because `substr` needs to know string indexes.

Yes, you are better off with a regex.

If your question is how to extract the digits from a string 00000ddddddd.jpg (for some number of zeros and non-zero digits) *anywhere* in a string, then you should use preg_match.

Here is a complete example which you can try on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
preg_match('/([1-9][0-9]+)\.jpg/', "I have a file called 0000482080.jpg somewhere", $matches);
echo "I like to call it: {$matches[0]}";
```

If the entire string is a filename, then use `intval` or casting as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: This way is ok for "000AA00" string ? "AA00" in result ?

Comment: Oops!  Good catch.  I edited my answer so that it does not pick up leading zeros.  So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression you can just do

```
preg_replace('/^0+/m','',$sourcestring);
```

`^` is the start of the string (here with the `m` modifier the start of a row)

`0+` means 1 or more zeros.

This regex will match all leading zeros and replace with an empty string.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u7bh)

Comment: As say to Ray Toal answer : This way is ok for "000AA00" string ? "AA00" in result ?

Comment: @bahamut100 I added a link to a regex test tool where you can see it. Yes it will also remove the leading 0 from "000AA00", is it this what you want?